# Android 5.0(lollipop) - The event function is shown in logcat by calling program but the screen does not move

Tags: android

1. Development environment

   - android phone version : 5.0(lollipop)
   - development tool : ADT(Build : v22.0.0-675183)
   - my app's minSdkVersion : API13
2. Problem Description

   I use the slide menu library(open source : [github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)).
   The main layout consists of a [ListView] with [ViewPager] and [Left Slide Menu].

   Before I open the left slide menu, it functions manually.
   However, **a scroll of listview and a swipe event in viewpager do not operate well after opening the left slide menu.**
   **To expatiate on this, the event function is shown in logcat by calling program but the screen does not move.**

   Please answer if you know it.

My Code

```
public class AndroidTestActivity extends FlagmentActivity implements OnPageChangeListener, OnClickListener {
private ListView listView;
private ViewPager mPager;
private SlidingMenu menu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    mAdapter = new MainListAdapter(this);

    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        ...
        }
    });

    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext()));

    menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.15f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new LeftSlideMenuListFragment(MainMenuActivity.this))
    .commit();

}


 private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    @Override 
    public int getCount() { 
        return 2;
    }

    @Override 
    public Object instantiateItem(View pager, int position) {
        View v = null;

        if(position==0) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu_01, null);
                                ...

        } else if(position==1) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu_02, null);
                                ...
        }
        ((ViewPager)pager).addView(v, 0);
        return v; 
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View pager, int position, Object view) {
        ((ViewPager)pager).removeView((View)view);
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) { 
        return view == obj; 
    }

    @Override public void finishUpdate(View arg0) { }
    @Override public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {}
    @Override public Parcelable saveState() { return null; }
    @Override public void startUpdate(View arg0) {}

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

 }

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if(menu.isMenuShowing()) {
            menu.showContent();
            mPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            mPager.invalidate();
        } else {
            finish();
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: why are you use not using the native navigation drawer?

Comment: native navigation drawer works only with version 5.0.
my app is deployed on Google app store.
so, must be performed in less than version 5.0.

Comment: wrong it does work on other versions also

Comment: I tried the navigation drawer. However, an exception is occurred....
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()' on a null object reference  ...

Comment: you should be using appcompat v7. also your comment does not help solve the problem. Suggest you to add more details and edit your post